# HTML detail element informations angular 2

Tags: html, angular, typescript, events

Hello I wonder if there is any way to send information about that details is closed or opened I mean:
`<details (click)="changeWrap($event)">`
I can't see in $event any informations about details's open.
I work on angular 2. Thanks :)

Comment: How you make sure if details are open or not? Do you have any class?

Comment: That's the point that Im not sure if it's opened or not, I want to be sure about that to set variables in class in ts file

Comment: What do you mean by open Details? are you talking about showing a div while open?

Comment: Can you provide some code please ?

Comment: do you need info about the details element in your component ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i write a simple component, using **@ViewChild**  we can get the element from the template.

then we can access the **open** attribute inside of it. when the user click the details element.

```
import { Component, ViewChild }          from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <details (click)='detailsClicked()' #detailsElement>
      <summary>Copyright 1999-2014.</summary>
      <p> - by Refsnes Data. All Rights Reserved.</p>
      <p>All content and graphics on this web site are the property of the company Refsnes Data.</p>
    </details>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  @ViewChild('detailsElement') detailsElement;

  detailsClicked() {
    setTimeout(() => { 
      console.log(this.detailsElement.nativeElement.open)
    }, 0); 
  }

}
```

i use the setTimeout() method in order to get the final state of detail element.

Comment: Thanks, well done, but I realized that IE and microsoft edge doesn't support <details> so i changed it to checkbox styled like a details :)

Answer (score 2):

Old topic, but you can try template variables. This saves you the `@ViewChild` in the `.ts`.

```js
<details #dtv
         (click)="changeWrap(!dtv.open)">
    <summary> Summary title </summary>
</details>
```

And for a more consistent behavior, you can put the `click` event on the `<summary>`.

```js
<details #dtv>
    <summary (click)="changeWrap(!dtv.open)"> Summary title </summary>
</details>
```